# failed to validate a newly established connection -

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot

I've seen some anwers for this particular question but nothing seems to work for me. I still get 'filed to validate' error. I've been developing this Spring Boot app in STS for about a month, and didn't have this exception until I created executable jar and run it on test server machine. When I start the app, all data loads in correctly, however after some time (few minutes) when I try to update or add new record, there's 'filed to validate' error in cmd from where I run executable jar.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/prod
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
server.port = 8085

spring.datasource.connection-test-query = SELECT 1
spring.datasource.test-while-idle=true
spring.datasource.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.max-active=10
spring.datasource.initial-size=5
spring.datasource.max-idle=5
spring.datasource.min-idle=1
spring.datasource.time-between-eviction-runs-millis=5000
spring.datasource.min-evictable-idle-time-millis=60000 

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Comment: that config won't work on Spring Boot 1.4 and later. data source specific properties have moved to nested namespaces (e.g. `spring.datasource.hikari.*` for HiarkiCP). Please try to narrow down the problem, your problem description is quite vague.

Comment: I'm not using Hikari (or I'm not aware of this fact). My spring-boot-starter-parent is 1.3.0 RC1

Comment: That was an example. Why are you using 1.3.0.RC1 when 1.3.8 is out? If you want someone to help you, please try to better describe the problem.

Comment: You also want to add the stacktrace/logging output to your question. Only the `application.properties` is a little thin.